# Instagram OAuth Response - 400 error, revoked access

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

We have just run into a new bug with our app, which has been working for months. Whenever new users come to the app to try to sign up (through Instagram) Instagram responds with this error:

{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "User has revoked access to this client"}

Of course, prior to this, the user grants the app access. So how could it be revoked? We have also checked with test accounts, and verified that the app does indeed have access by looking it up in settings.

There were a number of people (including us) on Stack Overflow experiencing issues a few days ago with Instagram OAuth, which appeared to have been resolved.

Is this a widespread issue? Is anyone else experiencing this or is it limited to our app?

Comment: which API call is giving this response ?